# How to fix the -like which searches for characters

Tags: powershell, for-loop, if-statement, password-generator

I'm trying to write a password generator in PowerShell everything works fine except the `if` statement. I am asking if the password contains any special characters or numbers. If it doesn't contain any of them it should output an error if it contains numbers or characters it should write the password.

I'm trying to do this with an array and ASCII. I'm writing the characters into an array with a for loop and later on, I'm converting them to the specific character I want.

This is for a school project I'm working on. I've tried to remove the brackets in the `if` statement but then it shows the password even without the special characters and numbers.

```
$RandomePassword = "abC!231"
for ($ASCII = 33  ; $ASCII -le 64 ; $ASCII++) {
    $char += @($ASCII)
} 

if ($RandomePassword -like ([char[]]$char -join "|")) {
    write (($RandomePassword -split '' | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join '')
} else {
    write "ERROR"
}
```

The expected result would be:

`$RandomePassword = "Abc!12"` ⇒ writes Password on Comand line
`$RandomePassword = "Abc"` ⇒ writes error

Comment: `-like` -> `-match`. You're building a regular expression as the reference value, but the `-like` operator is for [wildcard matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/supporting-wildcard-characters-in-cmdlet-parameters). See [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) for more information.

Comment: I think i got it now, when iam testing without the [char[]]$Zeichen -join "|" it works perfectly. Now i have just to find a way to do this with the array.

Thank you for your help